# How to hide the later pages and show pagination in jquery ajax response?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have list of pagination from ajax response. how to hide the later pages and show pagination according the limiter.

If the limiter is 5 have to show only 10 page links and hide later pages.

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 .. next

11 12 13 14 15.. next

I have tried to count the li length from the ajax response it doesn't show the count. how to get the count and hide and show later pages.

output:

```
next_page_num: <li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li>..



  success: function(response){  
                $("#listing_products").html("");
                $("#listing_products").html(response.html_content);
                $("ul.pagination").html("");
                $("ul.pagination").html(response.next_page_num);

                if(page_limit==5){

                    var product_listing_count = response.next_page_num;



                    if($(product_listing_count).length>8){

//How to hide after 8th pages and hide later pages add next to 8th page

 ));

                    }               

                    $("ul.pagination").html("");
                    $("ul.pagination").html(response.next_page_num);

                }
```

Comment: Provide minimal working  implementation of what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

vanilla JS solution here, in which I used

- regular expression

  ```
  var regex = /<li[^>]*>\d+<\/li[^>]*>/g
  ```

  This matches any pattern like `<li>digits</li>`
- [`String.prototype.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), which gets me an array of results that matches the pattern above
- [`Array.prototype.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), which gets my the first `limitTo` items (in this case, `5`)
- [`...`Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), which helps me easily concatenate two arrays
- And, lastly, [`Array.prototype.join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join), which helps me get my array back into a string

Working solution:

```js
var regex = /<li[^>]*>\d+<\/li[^>]*>/g
var product_listing_count = "<li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li><li>7</li><li>8</li><li>9</li><li>10</li><li>11</li>"
var productListingAsArray = product_listing_count.match(regex);
var limitTo = 5;
var continuousDots = "<li>...</li>"
var nextItem = "<li>next</li>"
var resultingArray = [...productListingAsArray.slice(0,limitTo),continuousDots,nextItem];
console.log(resultingArray.join(""));
```

Comment: I love [that answer about when regex should be used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: No, just follow the link and you will understand, haha !

Comment: That's a minor detail which you can adjust yourself. Added something but that's up to you

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `$.fn.find` function go through the children nodes of an element, so if there's no parent like `<ul>` there's no children...

Then:

```
$('<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li></ul>')
    .find('li').length;
```

> returns 6

And:

```
$('<li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li>')
    .find('li').length;
```

> returns 0

A simple way to get the length would be a `split/length`:

```
'<li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li>'
    .split('<li>').length - 1; 
 //-1 because there will be always a empty entry in the array
```

> returns 6

Or like Adelin sugested, use RegExp:

```
 '<li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li><li>5</li><li>6</li>'
      .match(/(<li>)/g).length
```

> returns 6

Comment: How should i take the length of li alone